# How to number the options in a wp_dropdown_pages() select?

Tags: dropdown, select

I'm using `wp_dropdown_pages()` but would like to number the options returned for the user.  So instead of something like...

```
<option value='http://someurl'>item one</option>
<option value='http://someurl'>item two</option>
<option value='http://someurl'>item three</option>
```

I end up with:

```
<option value='http://someurl'>1. page one</option>
<option value='http://someurl'>2. page two</option>
<option value='http://someurl'>3. page three</option>
```

How would one go about doing that with the output of `wp_dropdown_pages()`?

Comment: An alternative would be to construct the markup yourself with a `WP_Query` to grab the pages, rather than using the high level function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change

```
<option value='http://someurl'>item one</option>
<option value='http://someurl'>item two</option>
<option value='http://someurl'>item three</option>
```

to

```
<option value='http://someurl'>1. item one</option>
<option value='http://someurl'>2. item two</option>
<option value='http://someurl'>3. item three</option>
```

we can utilize the `list_pages` filter from the `Walker_PageDropdown::start_el()` method.

Here's an example:

```
// Add filter
add_filter( 'list_pages', 'wpse_itemize', 10, 2 );

// Display dropdown
wp_dropdown_pages();

// Remove filter
remove_filter( 'list_pages', 'wpse_itemize' );
```

where the callback is defined as:

```
function wpse_itemize( $title, $page )
{
    static $nr = 1;     
    return sprintf( '%d. %s', $nr++, $title );
}
```

### Update

For the custom `wp_dropdown_posts()` function you could try:

```
if( function_exists( 'wp_dropdown_posts' ) )
{
    // Add filter
    add_filter( 'esc_html', 'wpse_itemize' );

    // Display dropdown
    wp_dropdown_posts();

    // Remove filter
    remove_filter( 'esc_html', 'wpse_itemize' );
}
```

where the callback is defined as:

```
function wpse_itemize( $safe_text )
{
    static $nr = 1;     
    return sprintf( '%d. %s', $nr++, $safe_text );
}
```

### Note

I was just curious how we could add post post type support to `wp_dropdown_pages()` and got it through with this hack:

```
global $wp_post_types;
$wp_post_types['post']->hierarchical = true;
wp_dropdown_pages( [ 'post_type' => 'post' ] );
$wp_post_types['post']->hierarchical = false;
```

but I **absolutely don't recommend** this, it was just a test to see if I could find "any" theoretical workaround.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for the function I gave and I will be accepting it.  Unfortunately for me, I am using an alternative to get posts rather than pages. I had expected that the solution would probably work the same regardless but it doesn't and I'm not able to see exactly what to fix.  I'm using the wp_dropdown_posts() function found in this plugin:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dropdown-posts/ any chance you could help with how to modify your answer to work with that function?

Comment: Hot damn that worked perfectly!  =)  Interesting post_type hack as well, but I won't be needing it as your other solution works great with the existing function.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a workaround @JonathanvanClute

Comment: OOPS, one small but annoying detail.  My posts are being returned in ASC order, but after numbering them the numbers are ASC but the posts are in DESC alphabetical order.  Not sure why your solution has caused this... any suggestions?

Comment: I just used`wp_dropdown_posts()`  with default arguments where the  ordering is `DESC` by default. I guess you would modify the ordering with `wp_dropdown_posts( [ 'sort_order' => 'ASC' ] )`. Hope I understood this correctly. @JonathanvanClute

Comment: Yeah I have sort_order added to the $args that I pass in, and it works fine until I add your solution.  Very strange... I will continue to experiment.  Thanks again!

Comment: ok no problem, glad you sorted it out ;-) @JonathanvanClute

Comment: I actually also  thought of making `wp_dropdown_pages()` hierarchical as well, but messing with globals are not my style as it almost always causes a wild goose(`n`) chase in later years when you forgot that you have messed with a global ;-). As you said ***absolutely don't recommend***

Comment: yes, messing around with these globals could end in a giant cloud of goose feathers, where we wouldn't be able to see a thing ;-) @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI I created a function to add `wp_dropdown_posts()`:

https://github.com/tripflex/wp_dropdown_posts